# Add local script into <head> tag using react-helmet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-helmet

I have a React 16 project that is already using [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet). I want to add a specific  inside of the  tag. I was hoping I could put the script in my project's `src/scripts` folder and import it/add it under the `<Helmet>` tag

The following works:

```js
<Helmet>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    {`
      (function(m,n,e,t,l,o,g,y){
       ...
       })(window,document,window['_fs_namespace']...)
    `}
  </script>
</Helmet>
```

I was hoping to make it cleaner by extracting `(function(m,n,e,t,l,o,g,y)...` into the `src/scripts/utils.js` file and import it that way. I tried fidling with `<script src=..>` but haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your utility function to the src/scripts/utils.js and "export" it, like this:

```
// src/scripts/utils.js
const myFunction = () => {
  ...
}
window.myFunction = myFunction
```

And in your main file:

```
{`
  window.myFunction(window,document,window['_fs_namespace']...)
`}
```